# Partial localization recognition in WP7 app

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, localization

I've been working on the localisations of a WP7 app and although most of the languages appear to operate as expected at runtime I'm having trouble with a few.

For example, Russian, Polish, Swedish, Norwegian, Portuguese and Hungarian don't appear to be working but both Traditional & Simplified Chinese, Greek and Danish do (there are other languages which also work).

The app's neutral culture is set to "en", although I also tried "en-GB" originally.

I'm sure it's something to do with culture codes as I can't find any reference to similar problems with partial language support anywhere.

I've enabled the following cultures within the project file itself:

```
<SupportedCultures>en;da-DK;de-DE;el-GR;es;es-ES;de-DE;fr;fr-FR;it-IT;zh-TW;zh-CN;hu-HU;no;nb-NO;pt-PT;pl-PL;ru;ru-RU;sv-SE;</SupportedCultures>
```

In that list, everything up to Hungarian seems to be fine. I've also tried adding short culture codes and duplicating resource files accordingly (e.g. Russian and Spanish) in case I'd got it completely wrong, but even the MSDN documentation seems to indicate that all the above are supported on WP7.1.

Example use of resource in XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalisedResources.res_Name, 
    Source={StaticResource LocalisedStrings}}" />
```

Happy to provide more detail on the implementation to assist answers but I'm sure it's just something simple I've missed (i.e. PEBKAC). I've checked that all the resource files have the same attributes, correct spelling e.g. Resource\Resources.hu-HU.resx, Public modifiers and only contain string resources.

Using VS2010, WP OS 7.1 and the standard emulator to check & test.

Has anyone encountered anything similar, or know of any steps to try and resolve?

Thanks

Comment: I have localised for Russian,Swedish,Portuguese. My resx files are named as AppResources.ru.resx and are not placed in folders.

Comment: Thanks Alfah - Do you only use "ru" as the culture code for Russian, and what culture codes do you use for Swedish and Portuguese?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

Not 100% sure what the problem was but cleaned / deleted bin folder content manually / rebuilt solution and it's working in all languages.

It looks like something got caught between builds and was not correctly deployed during emulator testing but I can't see anything in the build output or output console to indicate exactly what that was.